# how to make a bezier curve using a tool(curvature)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```js
function letraT1(c2d) { 
 c2d.beginPath();

 c2d.moveTo(0.376, 0.32);
       c2d.bezierCurveTo(0.349,0.223,0.426,0.217,0.453,0.399);
 c2d.moveTo(0.376, 0.32);
 c2d.closePath();
 
}

function main() {
    var c2d = document.getElementById("acanvas").getContext("2d");
    example_space(c2d);
}

function enter(c, dx, dy, sx, sy) {
    c.save();
    c.translate(dx,dy);
    c.scale(sx,sy);
}
 
function leave(c, fs, ss) {
    c.restore();
    c.fillStyle = fs;
    c.strokeStyle = ss;
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
}
 
function leave_plus(c, lw, fs, ss) { 
 c.restore();
   c.fillStyle = fs;
   c.strokeStyle = ss;
 c.lineWidth = lw;
   c.fill();
   c.stroke();
}

function castelo(c) {
    c.strokeStyle = "#00B4E9";
    c.lineWidth = 0.01;
    //has others things here but they wasnt relevant for the problem so i didnt put.
    
    enter(c, 0.1,0.15, 0.5, 0.45);
    letraT1(c);
    leave_plus(c, 0, "#211F22", "#211F22");
    //
    //
    //
   
    
}

function example_space(c) {
    enter(c, 20,20, 400,505);
    castelo(c);
    leave(c, c.fillStyle, c.strokeStyle);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="novaversao.js">

    


        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="main();">
        <canvas id="acanvas" width="1028" height="1028" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using this tool(https://canvature.appspot.com/#absolute=true&starting=376,32&bezier=349,223,426,217,453,399) to design a bezier curve, but when I try do this in code it's very strange in the way that it looks.

So my question is how can I make my curve look like the curve I draw in canvature.

I draw the curve from this image:[image]

Comment: Do not use the `fill()` method. You only want to use `stroke()`

Comment: @RandyCasburn 
In leave_plus i remove the fill and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference my comment.

Remove the `fill()` calls in both methods. The `fill()` method closes the path and fills the resulting shape with the `fillStyle` color.

You must remove both because you call both functions.

```js
function letraT1(c2d) { 
 c2d.beginPath();

 c2d.moveTo(0.376, 0.32);
       c2d.bezierCurveTo(0.349,0.223,0.426,0.217,0.453,0.399);
 c2d.moveTo(0.376, 0.32);
 c2d.closePath();
 
}

function main() {
    var c2d = document.getElementById("acanvas").getContext("2d");
    example_space(c2d);
}

function enter(c, dx, dy, sx, sy) {
    c.save();
    c.translate(dx,dy);
    c.scale(sx,sy);
}
 
function leave(c, fs, ss) {
    c.restore();
    c.fillStyle = fs;
    c.strokeStyle = ss;
//    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
}
 
function leave_plus(c, lw, fs, ss) { 
 c.restore();
   c.fillStyle = fs;
   c.strokeStyle = ss;
 c.lineWidth = lw;
//   c.fill();
   c.stroke();
}

function castelo(c) {
    c.strokeStyle = "#00B4E9";
    c.lineWidth = 0.01;
    //has others things here but they wasnt relevant for the problem so i didnt put.
    
    enter(c, 0.1,0.15, 0.5, 0.45);
    letraT1(c);
    leave_plus(c, 0, "#211F22", "#211F22");
    //
    //
    //
   
    
}

function example_space(c) {
    enter(c, 20,20, 400,505);
    castelo(c);
    leave(c, c.fillStyle, c.strokeStyle);
}
```

```css
canvas {
 background-color: #00B4E9
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="novaversao.js">

    


        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="main();">
        <canvas id="acanvas" width="1028" height="1028" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I has a background that I need to fill but I don't put him here because it wasn't relevant to the problem

Comment: What has a background? A curve does not have a background, it is a path. You can create a shape with a curve that you fill, but that isn't a curve. Which do you want?

Comment: I'm copying this image(https://d.gr-assets.com/books/1331696371l/333538.jpg) I already has the castle and the eye draw, i need just to draw the letters

Comment: the first problem is solved but how can I make the letter look like I want?

Comment: Yes, please rerun my code snippet. You will see the blue background you desire. I have answered your question...please do not change your question in a comment.

Comment: I didnt change the question... has a said "how to make my curve look like..:"

Comment: If the first problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer. Then, create a new question to ask how to place text onto canvas.